# Spring mvc:resources tag

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to get the static resources to put inside my web app by using tag  but it doesn't work.
My beans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

My JSP file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<spring:url value="/resources/style.css" var="styleCss" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/resources/style.css"/>' />
```

My file structure:

[image]

I have tried many ways but they're all doesn't work.

Please help me.
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
```

since you have kept the resources inside the WEB-INF you need to include that in the resources path.